# Paging in MVC Telerik Grid not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I am working on a project that would display Graduated and current student on a page. I rendered that information on the client side using a telerik grid. The page has two radio button - one radio button for displaying graduated students and the other for displaying current students. Every time a user click on one of the radio button, it does not post. There are more current than graduate students. When the user access the last page for current student and then click on the graduate radio button, it does not show any graduate students. The telerik page did not update as expected. The undergrad page has 23 pages while the graduate one has 18.  Accessing the graduate page is still on page 23 even though we have 18 pages.

I follow this example and added a

```
.Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled((bool)ViewData["paging"]).PageTo(1))
```

It does not go back to page one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out how to make this paging work properly. As a result, I created two session variables, that have values true or false,  and I redirected the user to the same page setting the grad and undergrad students flag to false or true. If the user came in for the first time, the grad students flag was set to false, and the page would not redirect. The same logic was created for the undergrad student.